# XSLT Exclude Specific Tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem i am trying to resolve in an XSLT but i an unable to find a solution. The example below is related to a payment system it is adding items to a basket then removing them. The out XML provides a audit trail of actions conducted on a basket.

#### Senario:

Add Item (Id 1)

Add Item (Id 1) With a price change

Void Item (Id 1)

Void Item (Id 1) With a price change

Add Item (Id 1)

Add Item (Id 1)

#### Expected Outcome

Remove:

Add Item (Id 1)

Add Item (Id 1) With a price change

#### Output XML Contains

Void Item (Id 1)

Void Item (Id 1) With a price change

Add Item (Id 1)

Add Item (Id 1)

Input XML:

```
<xml>
    <product void="false">
        <sequence_number>1</sequence_number>
        <item_id>11111111</item_id>
        <price>12</price>
    </product>
    <product void="false">
        <sequence_number>2</sequence_number>
        <item_id>11111111</item_id>
        <price>12</price>
        <price_change>
            <price>10</price>
        </price_change>
    </product>
    <product void="true">
        <sequence_number>3</sequence_number>
        <item_id>11111111</item_id>
        <price>12</price>
        <price_change>
            <price>10</price>
        </price_change>
    </product>
    <product void="true">
        <sequence_number>4</sequence_number>
        <item_id>11111111</item_id>
        <price>12</price>
    </product>
    <product void="false">
        <sequence_number>5</sequence_number>
        <item_id>11111111</item_id>
        <price>12</price>
    </product>
    <product void="false">
        <sequence_number>6</sequence_number>
        <item_id>11111111</item_id>
        <price>12</price>
    </product>
</xml>
```

Expected outcome:

```
<xml>
    <product void="true">
        <sequence_number>3</sequence_number>
        <item_id>11111111</item_id>
        <price>12</price>
        <price_change>
            <price>10</price>
        </price_change>
    </product>
    <product void="true">
        <sequence_number>4</sequence_number>
        <item_id>11111111</item_id>
        <price>12</price>
    </product>
    <product void="false">
        <sequence_number>5</sequence_number>
        <item_id>11111111</item_id>
        <price>12</price>
    </product>
    <product void="false">
        <sequence_number>6</sequence_number>
        <item_id>11111111</item_id>
        <price>12</price>
    </product>
</xml>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="//product[@void='false']">
        
        <xsl:if test="item_id != //product[@void='true']/item_id">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem with this is that it is deleting all products that are not voided and have the same id and not taking into account the number of void items vs the number of none void items.

If you have 1 void item it should only delete one product that is not voided but has exactly the same tags as itself

Comment: Unless I'm missing something your example shows that all of the `item_id` are the same which means your if statement will never be true. Also your if statement would only be checking against the first `product` each time. Not sure if that was your intent either.

Comment: Correct all items are the same because of the context, you have an item in a bag, which you add then remove then add again, so it always has the same id, but the problem is you VOIDED one of the items and i was to illustrate that in the output by remove ONLY 1 of the products that hasnt been void and matches the product nodes exactly. Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `products` always show up in sequence you can do a check against the preceding-sibling for true and then compare the `item_id`. Since your first two items don't have a void transaction preceding them it would not process those. So you can update your if statement to the below:

```
<xsl:if test="item_id = preceding-sibling::product[@void='true']/item_id">
```

That will then match your expected output.

Comment: What happens is they are not order? Which is very my how this will work. You will add 3 of the same item into a bag then cancel the first but the cancel will have a sequence number of 4 but cancel sequence 2

Comment: So then how do you know which product is actually being voided to remove? At this point all of the examples show that the information contained in each product is nearly identical to each other. So if it isn't in sequence I'm not sure how you determine what action is for what product.